# Why isn't rc.local executed?

Tags: boot, scripts, upstart

I am PXE booting some Ubuntu machines in a cluster. All of a sudden my `rc.local` script has stopped working.

I've check the permission of `/etc/rc.local`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1087 Jan 14 11:04 /etc/rc.local
```

I've checked that `rc.local` is symlinked in the following folders:

```
/etc/rc2.d 
/etc/rc3.d
/etc/rc4.d 
/etc/rc5.d
```

They all symlink to `/etc/init.d/rc.local`.

I've tried to output echo lines from the script to `/tmp/test.out` but no luck. When I execute the `rc.local` script after the machines has booted, it works fine.

What can cause `rc.local` not to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working. Dunno if this is the best solution, but works for now. I moved the `/etc/init.d/rc.local` and the `/etc/rc.local` to a different location, and the I ran

```
update-rc.d rc.local remove
```

Afterwards I moved the two scripts back into place and ran

```
update-rc.d rc.local defaults
```

It now appears to be working correct.