# rc.local is not restored after initscripts reinstall

Tags: 14.04, startup, restore, init.d

I was having a hard time trying to make rc.local run on startup, which i still haven't achieved, and would appreciate any help with that.

The main problem right now is that I decided to follow [this advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243044/why-isnt-rc-local-executed) and accidentally deleted `/etc/init.d/rc.local`

I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall initscripts`, but it doesn't seem to restore restore it

Maybe any of you could give me a text copy of rc.local, or maybe a link to where I could download it, so I would just put it back there manually?
I'm on Ubuntu **14.04**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover the default version of some configuration file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/627017/how-do-i-recover-the-default-version-of-some-configuration-file)

Comment: wouldn't consider a duplicate, since, as I mentioned, use of `dpkg -S` and `apt-get install --reinstall` didn't solve anything

Comment: I don't suggest using `--reinstall` at all.

Comment: yes, but your file in that question was not provided by any packages, and rc.local is

Comment: What? O.o I provided two examples, one which is provided by a package and one which isn't.

Comment: oh, ok now I see it. In this case, your solution is better. but for me it was easier to simply copypaste the contents of the missing file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rc.local
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Run /etc/rc.local if it exist
### END INIT INFO


PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start() {
    if [ -x /etc/rc.local ]; then
            [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_begin_msg "Running local boot scripts (/etc/rc.local)"
        /etc/rc.local
        ES=$?
        [ "$VERBOSE" != no ] && log_end_msg $ES
        return $ES
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    do_start
        ;;
    restart|reload|force-reload)
        echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
    stop)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

Permissions are 0755:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 782 Mar 13  2014 /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

Comment: you misunderstood. it's not the **/etc/rc.local** that's missing (which would not be a big deal). it's **/etc/init.d/rc.local**

Comment: I've fixed it...